# ios swapping UILabel in UItableView

Tags: dictionary, swap, direction

I am currently developing an ios map application.

One of the feature allow user to get direction information. I have created a UItableview with 2 static cell. 1st cell display current location and    the 2nd cell display destination. Both cell contain an UILabel which display the text.

My question is how do i allow user to swap the 1st cell with the 2nd so they can chose to get direction from destination location to current location instead of the default.

Any idea on how to go about doing this. Is there anyway for me to drag and drop the UILabel to swap both  label or is there a way to display a button in between the cell that allow user to swap like what google map does?

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with displaying a button for swapping. All the button will do is swap the source and destination for you and reload the table.

Just a quick writeup with many assumptions here:

```
@interface myVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
{
  NSString* _source;
  NSString* _dest;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
@end
```

And then in the implementation:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell* cell;

  if (indexPath.row == 0)
  {
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SourceCell"];
     cell.textLabel.text = source;
  }
  else // indexPath.row == 1
  {
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DestCell"];
     cell.textLabel.text = dest;
  }

  return cell;
}

- (IBAction)swap:(id)sender
{
   NSString* temp = source;
   source = dest;
   dest = temp;
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```